# Subroutines as parameters in Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
in:-
  male(jack),
  female(rose).

test(in):-
  male(X) -> write("True"),
  female(X) -> write("True").
```

I'm testing whether it's possible to pass subroutines as parameters. But I'm having errors when calling test(in). in SWI

Comment: It is possible to pass `predicates` as parameters. To execute a predicate in a variable use call/1. See: [Meta call predicates](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=metacall).

Comment: Based on the way you structed the code either you are not understanding Prolog, or I am not understanding your question. Also using `->` without `;` is not what I would expect to see it code.